# How does the parenthesis at the end of a javascript function supposed to work

Tags: javascript

I consider myself a pretty strong javascript coder and am familiar with most all of the javascript syntax. But have been puzzled by the following syntax:

```
function() {
    return function() {

    }
} ();
```

Can someone explain what the parenthesis at the end is supposed to be used for?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the expression:

```
(function() {
    return function() {

    }
})
```

Evaluates to a function (without a name in this case) that returns some other function.

Adding `()`:

```
(function() {
    return function() {

    }
})();
```

Would simply *call* that function.

Another way to write this would be:

```
var foo = function() {
        return function() {

        }
    };

foo();
```

Comment: So it's just a different way to write the same pattern as your third example? Okay, I get it. Thanks. Good explanation.

Comment: @tonejac - Correct.  It's a bit more compact, because it doesn't use a variable to reference the function you just created.  It just declares it, then calls it immediately.

Comment: Okay, connections are now firing in my brain, that makes total sense now! Thx.

Comment: It's called an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE). [Reference](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: Excellent!  Really, the only advantage of using the `foo` variable is you could keep a reference around to call that function again if you wanted.  The first example would be ideal if you only needed to call the function once.

Answer (score 2):

It is a self invoking function. Meaning a function that declares and calls itself.

Another form would be:

```
(function() {
    return function() {
    }
}());
```